# Read information inside PDF?

Tags: pdf, automation

I'd like to automate the invoices I receive from a particular company. Unfortunately they name the files very strangely and the filename is not at all related to invoice number, or date. So I'm trying to find something to extract information from inside the PDF. I would look for particular strings and numbers. I can think of Spotlight that would be able to do that, but I don't think that's the best way. Suggestions and solutions to this particular problem are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of things I use [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php). I have a very easy way to filter PDF contents based on rules. The below image contains a rule that I use to organise my invoices. Hazel keeps watching a folder, and acts on every new file there based on your defined rules.

[image: Screenshot of Hazel configuration]

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. I forgot that I can match the contents as well and make a token out of it. That should do it. I give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing one of the files it is difficult to give specific advice. I would try an Automator workflow. There is a PDF library which can perform many actions e.g. Extract metadata from PDF documents, Extract text from PDF documents

Comment: The PDF's have readable text in them. What other information would you need?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to buy Hazel - just create an auto-running Automator script that puts files in a specified folder that were downloaded from the specified website/s.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the original question. It doesn't say how Automator can do what I've been originally asking.